# How to fetch only a limited number of joined results?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Let's suppose, I have the following tables:

projects

- id INT
- name VARCHAR
- owner_id INT

versions

- id INT
- project_id INT
- tag VARCHAR
- created_at DATETIME

owners

- ... (it's now irrelevant)

I would like to retrieve a set of projects, and I would like to join only the newest version for each project. A DISTINCT query isn't good for this purpose, because it limits the colums returned from the query, however I need all the columns.

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
    projects.id, projects.name, projects.owner_id
FROM
    projects
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT versions.id, versions.project_id, versions.created_at, versions.tag FROM versions ORDER BY versions.created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
ON
    projects.id = versions.project_id
WHERE
    projects.owner_id = 1
```

More generally, I would like to return a limited number of joined results based on a specific criteria.

But I'm wondering, is there a better solution for this? A nested query doesn't seem to be elegant, and probably isn't efficient either. Primarily I'm looking for an SQLite compatible solution, but if there are better ways for other SQL engines, I'm interested in it too, as I already bumped into to this problem in the past with MySQL for example.

**UPDATE:** I would like to give a further illustration of the problem by a wrong solution. The simplest way would be to do this:

```
SELECT
    projects.id, projects.name, versions.tag, versions.created_at
FROM
    projects
INNER JOIN
    versions
ON
    projects.id = versions.project_id
WHERE
    projects.owner_id = 1
ORDER BY
    versions.created_at DESC;
```

This is just a simple JOIN structure. Let's suppose, it will give the following dataset as a result:

```
#   id  name        tag     created_at
1   1   project1    v2.3    2018-05-08 18:33:42
2   5   project5    v4.0    2018-05-08 11:19:07
3   3   project3    v1.8    2018-05-07 21:41:49
4   5   project5    v3.18   2018-05-07 07:00:26
5   8   project8    v3.12   2018-05-06 08:59:01
6   11  project11   v1.9    2018-05-05 14:27:31
7   5   project5    v3.17   2018-05-04 11:48:22
8   1   project1    v2.2    2018-05-04 05:11:46
9   2   project2    v5.5    2018-05-03 23:08:57
10  7   project7    v6.8    2018-05-03 12:17:33
```

The solution is wrong, because it returns unnecessary rows too. What I would need from this dataset, is row #1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10.
Because it is ordered by versions.created_at field in descending order, and I need the first result, i.e. the most recent of each project.

This is why I would need some sort of "selective LIMIT", which takes the versions.project_id field into account, similarly as a SELECT DISTINCT query would do, however, I need to return nearly all the fields from the table, not only the versions.project_id.

I am wondering, is there a "well-known" solution to this problem, which I don't know about?

Comment: I can't follow your logic because I don't know what tables the columns come from.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the column names for my example query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ROW_NUMBER with partition on id of projects and order of created_at like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_no
    FROM
        projects
    INNER JOIN
        versions ON projects.id = versions.project_id) AS tbl
WHERE row_no = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I'll experiment with it, when I get home. So far it looks interesting. I'll accept your solution after I tested it.

Comment: It did! Thank you!